# How do I extract data from this NodeList?

Tags: javascript, nodelist

I need to extract a particular data property from a `NodeList`. I have no problems getting data from arrays or objects in general, but this `NodeList` is beyond me! It doesn't work even if I use `Array.from()` to turn it into an array.

This is the relevant code:

[image]

And this is what it logs:

[image]

In the log on line 173, the closed arrays contain all the data I need, but I simply don't understand how to go there. When I try to go to an index there it just opens up the path coordinates.

I will also add the code image as text, it doesn't have any lines though:

```
let test = d3.selectAll(".unit")
    console.log(test)
    console.log(test._groups)
    console.log(test._groups[0])
    console.log(test._groups[0][0])
```

EDIT: To be more specific, the data I need is a "**data**" property inside the array below the nodelist (?), compare to the previous image of the log on line 173:
[image]

EDIT2: To be even more clear: When I open the nodelist in the console, I also get an array, and it is only the array that interests me. I don't understand this data structure, how the array is related to the nodelist, but I have tried to access the indexes of the array in a variety of ways and nothing has worked.

Comment: What data exactly do you need? The last line shows a path element, which is what the arrays contain.

Comment: I edited the post and added a more specific image at the bottom. Will check out the answers below now to see if it helps me.

Comment: Those are element properties so `test._groups[0][0]` contains that data. E.g. `console.log(test._groups[0][2].ariaAtomic)` prints the first property shown on the screenshot.

Comment: No, test._groups[0][0] is exactly what I tried above, and it only outputs a path with coordinates. test._groups[0][2].ariaAtomic gives an error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw 
an expression".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NodeList` objects are collections of nodes. In some cases, the `NodeList` is *live*, which means that changes in the DOM automatically update the collection.
In other cases, the `NodeList` is *static*, where any changes in the DOM does not affect the content of the collection. The `document.querySelectorAll()` method returns a static `NodeList`, for instance.

It's possible to loop over the items in a NodeList using a for loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < myNodeList.length; i++) {
  let item = myNodeList[i];
}
```

`for...of` loops will loop over NodeList objects correctly:

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
for (let checkbox of list) {
  checkbox.checked = true;
}
```

You can use [item()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/item) method to get an item by its index. For instance, this is how you can get `id` of the first `<div>` on some page:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div").item(0).id
```

In your case, you have an array and it contains an element of type `NodeList`.
So, when you do `test._groups[0]` you get the first element of your array and this element is `NodeList` and you need to work with it as with NodeList (see above)! For instance:

```
const arr = [1,2]; // simple array
// arr[0] is 1.
// in your case you have an array, but elements in that array are of type NodeList 
// (that's why console shows something like [NodeList(...)])

// when you get something from your array - it will be NodeList
// hence you can iterate over it or get some particular item like
test._groups[0].item(0).ariaAtomic
```

There are a lot more useful methods. Check [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) for more details.

Comment: Thanks but this does not work in my case, see the edits in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

To extrat data from nodeList you must loop your node list and the stock nodList elemnts in otheer tab

```
var list = node.childNodes; 

// Using for..of 
for(var value of list.values()) { 
  console.log(value); 
}

[check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/values][1]
```

Comment: This does not work in my case, see the edits in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

NodeList objects are collections of nodes.

You can loop through a node list by using the [NodeList.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/length) property and read the innerHTML of it as follows.

And refer the document for more knowlege

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

var gross = "";
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   gross += items[i].innerHTML;
}
```

and also you can loop through the

Comment: This is no ordinary node list, and the above example doesn't seem to work... se the edits in my initial post.